# Convert from naive local daylight time to naive local standard time in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, timestamp, timezone, timezone-offset

I have hourly data records that were recorded in local daylight time (for me this is US/Pacific). These will be read in through csv. A gap exists at the beginning of DST at 02:00 when we spring forward. In fall, I believe that the data collected at 01:00 PDT is labeled 01:00 and the next hour is labeled 02:00 (and assumes PST).

I would like to translate the timestamps so they play well with other data stored in PST. Below is my attempt, in which I have focused on only the index which should simplify discussion.

```
tndx = pd.DatetimeIndex(["2016-11-06 00:00",""2016-11-06 01:00","2016-11-06 02:00","2016-11-06 03:00"])
tndx.tz_localize('US/Pacific',ambiguous="NaT").tz_convert('Etc/GMT+8') 
print(tndx).tz_localize(None)
```

Output is:

```
DatetimeIndex(['2016-11-05 23:00:00-08:00',                       'NaT',
               '2016-11-06 02:00:00-08:00', '2016-11-06 03:00:00-08:00']
```

There are two things wrong about this. First, from the perspective of PST it seems like I am now missing two timestamps at 00:00 and 01:00. I get that the procedure is lossy, but I don't see that the procedure has to be lossy beyond one timestamp. I get an exception with `ambiguous = "infer"` because there are no redundant values. When I explicitly set this to a boolean array, as suggested by karajdaar, I don't lose the extra time point. However, the boolean list isn't that easy to come by -- I can't use tndx because it isn't tz aware yet. The only way I can think of is this circuitous route through datetime.dst that involves a separate DataFrame and conversion:

```
# Create a date range that spans the possible times and is hourly
ndx2 = pd.date_range(start=pd.Timestamp(2016,11,5), end =pd.Timestamp(2016,11,7),freq='H',tz='US/Pacific')

# Here is the determination of whether it is dst
isdst = [bool(x.dst()) for x in ndx2.to_pydatetime()]

# I use DataFrame indexing to perform the lookup 
# for values in my original index
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"isdst":isdst},index=ndx2.tz_localize(None))
df2 = df2.loc[~df2.index.duplicated(keep="last")]
ambig = df2[tndx]    # This is what I would use for ambiguous
```

Second, I used Etc/GMT+8 because I essentially blundered into discovering it gives the right offsets and timestamps, particularly after I make the stamps naive again. If I do not strip the time zone information (ie without the last `tz_convert(None)`) the output would be:

```
>>> tndx.tz_localize('US/Pacific',ambiguous='NaT').tz_convert('Etc/GMT+8')
DatetimeIndex(['2016-11-05 23:00:00-08:00',                       'NaT',
               '2016-11-06 02:00:00-08:00', '2016-11-06 03:00:00-08:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns, Etc/GMT+8]', freq=None)
```

The offsets in this case look fine, but the timezone in the dtype seems misleading and in any event why is a time zone called GMT+8 giving offsets of -8? What am I not understanding about these conversions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The offsets in this case look fine, but the timezone in the dtype seems misleading and  in any event why is a time zone called GMT+8 giving offsets of -8? What am I not  understanding about these conversions?

I'm posting to this question because looking for the answer brought me here and I found more information.

The pandas timezone conversion functionality appears to be based on the [IANA Time Zone Database](https://www.iana.org/time-zones)

In the etcetera file of the time zone database is the handy note

> Be consistent with POSIX TZ settings in the Zone names,
> even though this is the opposite of what many people expect.
> POSIX has positive signs west of Greenwich, but many people expect
> positive signs east of Greenwich.  For example, TZ='Etc/GMT+4' uses
> the abbreviation "-04" and corresponds to 4 hours behind UT
> (i.e. west of Greenwich) even though many people would expect it to
> mean 4 hours ahead of UT (i.e. east of Greenwich).

See also the [Wikipedia entry for IANA time zones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones), which says

> The special area of "Etc" is used for some administrative zones, particularly for "Etc/UTC" which represents Coordinated Universal Time. In order to conform with the POSIX style, those zone names beginning with "Etc/GMT" have their sign reversed from the standard ISO 8601 convention. In the "Etc" area, zones west of GMT have a positive sign and those east have a negative sign in their name (e.g "Etc/GMT-14" is 14 hours ahead of GMT).

Comment: Unfortunately, my question seemed to really be two questions, some of which may not have an answer. This, however, is a great piece of information. I've had to make peace with the flipped sign a long time ago ... at least now I know it is deliberate.

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot use "infer" as you don't have redundant values, you can pass in a boolean array to indicate True if day light times is in effect (in this case lets assume its not in effect)

```
print(tndx.tz_localize('US/Pacific',ambiguous=[False, False, False]).tz_convert('Etc/GMT+8'))
```

According to the documentation this flag is only applicable for ambiguous times for which you have only 1 in this case.

Then to get naive time stamps

```
print(tndx.tz_localize('US/Pacific',ambiguous=[False, False, False]).tz_localize(None))
```